# Magento 2 - How to stop order success email programatically

Tags: magento2, order-email

I am creating a order programatically in magento 2. What property I need to set on **$order** object so order success email will not trigger. I have tried below methods with **(bool) false**, parameter but no succes.

```
$order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);
$order->setEmailSent(false);
$order->setSendEmail(false);
```

Comment: See here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102992/magento2-stop-standard-order-email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this in newer versions (2.2.7+) is to use a plugin.

app/code/MagePal/DisableEmail/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity">
    <plugin name="magePalDisableEmailPlugin" sortOrder="1"
            type="MagePal\DisableEmail\Plugin\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentityPlugin"/>
</type>
```

app/code/MagePal/DisableEmail/Plugin/Order/Email/Container/OrderIdentityPlugin.php

```
Class OrderIdentityPlugin {

   public function __construct(
      .....

   ) {
      ...
   }

   public function afterIsEnabled(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $subject, $result)
   {
       if( some condition ){
           result = false;
       }

       return $result;
   }      

}
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked as expected.

Comment: How can the payment method or order information be retrieved in the afterIsEnabled function? thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by overiding the

```
send(Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false)
```

In

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see here at below path :

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php

You can override this **public function send(Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false)** function

Or

You can set from admin (It's better) to disable it instead of programmatically :

```
Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Email -> Order -> Enabled
```

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: I need to do that for a specific order that I am creating programatically. It will disable for all orders, that's something not required here.